# Return column with running sequence number Oracle

Tags: sql, oracle

My simple query returns data like this:

```
SELECT column1, column2 FROM table1

COLUMN1   COLUMN2
-------   -------
CA         A
CA         B
CB         C
CB         D
```

I want to return column3 with these values (for same COLUMN1 value, I want to return same sequence number):

```
COLUMN3
-------
1
1
2
2
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `analytic` function `DENSE_RANK`.

```
SELECT column1, 
       column2,
       DENSE_RANK() OVER(ORDER BY column1) as "column3"
 FROM table1
```

See the following for some examples - [oracle-base.com/articles/misc/rank-dense-rank-first-last-analytic-functions.php#dense_rank](http://oracle-base.com/articles/misc/rank-dense-rank-first-last-analytic-functions.php#dense_rank)

Comment: The `PARTITION BY column1` should be removed.

Comment: I think if you partition by column1 the value of `DENSE_RANK ()` will always be 1

Comment: Yes, correct. The column1 should be grouped together and not for each set of values. Updated my answer.

Answer (score 2):

Try this query,

```
Select column1, column2, 
       dense_rank() over (order by column1) as column3 
from table1;
```